# Context menu in grid in ExtJS

Tags: extjs

I have a two context menu items inside my grid. The first one is "delete" and the second one is Disable or Enable. Delete context menu I have added as below

```
 var contextMenu = Ext.create('Ext.menu.Menu', {
                controller: 'sites',
                width: 250,
                plain: true,
                items: [{
                    text: 'Delete',
                    handler: function () {
                    },      
                }]
```

Now I wanted to add Disable or Enable inside the items as a context menu. By enable or disable I mean I need to check the state of that particular row of the grid i.e. if the state of the row is enabled then "Disable" option should be come in the context menu and if the state is disables then the "Enable" option should be come in the context menu. How can I check the state of the row and how can I put if else condition inside my items?  Below is the column for checking the enabling of the row.

```
columns: [
        {text:'Active',dataIndex:'enabled',flex:1 },
]
```

Comment: How do you open your menu? Can you share a fiddle? But basically i would suggest to use itemcontextmenu event or cellcontectmenu (preferred). There you get a reference to the table, from there to the grid and the event itself to show the menu using ie contextMenu.showAt(event.getXY()). Here the link for the classic framework: https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/7.2.0/classic/Ext.grid.Panel.html#event-itemcontextmenu

Comment: Context menu is getting opened once I right click on any items on the grid.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an [actioncolumn](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/7.2.0/classic/Ext.grid.column.Action.html) to do so. It renders an icon in the grid cell, where you can link a function thanks to the [handler](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/7.2.0/classic/Ext.grid.column.Action.html#cfg-handler) config.

Here you can check with the `record` parameter whether the selected row is active, and render conditionally the right option; for example:

```js
handler: function(view, rowIndex, colIndex, item, e, record, eOpts) {
  if (record.data.active) {
    openDisableMenu()
  } else {
    openEnableMenu()  
  }
}
```